# What ftp library to use in VB6

Tags: vb6, ftp, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

We are using the builtin ftp in VB6. (Drag and drop control)

The ftp dll that follows VB6 is tied to IE.
And after upgrading from IE6 to IE7 the DLL changes and makes it impossible to connect to a password protected ftp.

What ftp libraries/dll's are available to use from VB6? 
Preferably open sourced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any COM library will do the trick, for example a .NET dll compiled with the 'Register for COM Interop' attribute.

[This pure .NET piece of code](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/desktopapplications/article.php/c13163) might do the work for you.